# How to connect iPhone with MacBook using AirDrop?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, bluetooth, file-transfer, airdrop

I have MacBook pro and iPhone 5S. when I tried to send file from MacBook to iPhone using AirDrop my laptop not finding my iPhone. Is there is any solution or additional settings needed?

Comment: Are both devices connected to the same WiFi network? Is Bluetooth enabled on both?

Comment: yes both phone are connected on same wifi and bluetooth on and also airdrop is active on phone.

Comment: There are a whole bunch of answers for the questions listed in the "Related" column to the right, want to start with those?

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you need to turn off and back on AirDrop on both the Mac and the iPhone, while at it you should do the same for Wi-Fi and Bluetooth, that should solve the problem, it works every time for me.